# How to change the temprary directory for configure script?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, configure

When I run the configure script to build GNU global on Linux system, I got the message "cannot create temp file for here document: No space left on device".  Indeed, / disk was full.

So I tried to change temporary directory to another disk, and I set the environment variable TMPDIR, TMP, and TEMP to another disk directory, say /mnt/tmp.

I retried to run configure script, but I got the same message.  What's wrong?  Please give me any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the script to determine where it is failing and how it determines the temp directory location?

Comment: You'll need a bit more space to compile the thing anyway, so better clean up a little bit your disk...

Answer (score 4):

you could add the below statement at the beginning of your script.

export TMPDIR='DIRNAME'

where "DIRNAME" is any directory on which you have full permissions and has sufficient memory available in it

Answer (score 4):

you can override the location of the temporary directory during configure like so:

```
./configure TMPDIR=path/to/your/tmp/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If your / directory is full, and the program is trying to write to your /tmp directory, try renaming the tmp directory to something like tmp_old, then create a symbolic link to your new tmp folder like: ln -s /mnt/tmp /tmp

Comment: I would avoid this approach.